# Should I use StringBuilder or not?

Tags: java, string, concatenation, stringbuilder

I have below code in my application at **many** places. I am using it to prepare SQL queries.

**Approach 1:**

```
private String sampleMethod(String name) {
    //null check
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Welcome ");
    sb.append(name);
    sb.append(", Have a good day!");
    //System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
private String sampleMethod(String name) {
    //null check
    //System.out.println("Welcome " + name + ", Have a good day!");
    return "Welcome " + name + ", Have a good day!";
}
```

1. Which approach should I use?
2. Does both have same memory usage?

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK - The second approach will be converted to the first by the compiler automatically.  One of the use cases for using `StringBuilder` would be if you were doing `String` concatenation within a loop

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Thanks. Understood your point.

Comment: Please refere :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Comment: @Prabhaker, Thanks for the link. It explains much about it. `Anyone referring this question in future, should check out above link`.

Answer (score 1):

Internally both approaches are nearly the same. Use whatever makes your code easier to read and maintain. Worry over memory consumption and performance only when you have problems in that regard. That will be much less than you think.

Comment: As I am not much aware of how compiler works, thanks for pointing out that internally both approaches are the same.

Answer (score 1):

In modern versions of Java compilers, the idiom:

```
String x = a + b + c;
```

is internally transformed into:

```
String x = new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).append(c).toString();
```

so, unless you're working with a really old compiler, both would be practically the same.

That doesn't mean that `StringBuilder` is not useful any more, it can still be used in `for` and `while` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Stringbuilder does not re create object, in that case, the memory usages is better. But String do re create object. Other than that, both's functionality are same.